# Accessing Oracle DB express from within Java

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a basic Java application (with a GUI) that uses a linked list to add/remove/modify Customer objects and I want to store them in a database (Oracle DB express to be exact)?

As I understand it, I have to create a table with some tool, and the use that tool to auto-generate a Java class that would allow me to communicate with the DB. How far off am I with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make your question clear, What tool have you used to generate your java code?

I recommend you to avoid using code generation tool in case you want to learn in and out of Java.Here is an example of how you can connect your SWING application with Oracle DB,MySQL,Derby and many more other databases.

```
Connection con;
Statement smt;
ResultSet rs;
String user="databaseuser";
String pass="password";
String path="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Sampledb";  //put db url here

  try{
           con=DriverManager.getConnection(path, user, pass);
           smt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
           String SQL="SELECT *FROM Registered_users_tb "; //Your Query here
           rs=smt.executeQuery(SQL);
           rs.moveToInsertRow();
           //First param is db column name,second param is variable name
           rs.updateString("USERNAME", username); 
           rs.updateString("FNAME", fname);
           rs.updateString("MNAME", mname);
           rs.updateString("LNAME", lname);
           rs.updateString("GENDER", gender);
           rs.updateString("DEPARTMENT", dept);
           rs.insertRow();
           rs.close();
            smt.close();
      }
        catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Classname.this,err.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: I was considering downloading JDeveloper and following a long tutorial that I found on the Oracle website. I think I was supposed to create a database first and then JDeveloper would create a Java class that I could reuse in my project. (or something like that). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a complete new database, oracle provide a gui tool called DBCA. I found a couple of links to use this tool: [Link 1](http://www.snapdba.com/2013/05/creating-an-oracle-11g-database-using-dbca-non-asm/) and [Link 2](http://www.oraclenext.com/2017/07/creating-oracle-database-using-dbca-for.html)

This [tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-database-via-jdbc) teaches how to access an Oracle database. For accessing such an database you need additional drivers found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html). Here an short example how to access such a database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

class DatabaseAccess
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            String dbPath = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:myDatabase";
            String username = "user";
            String password = "password";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath, username, password);

            if(connection != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connected with database");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet results = statementt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable");

                while(result.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(result.getString("myString"));  
                }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch(SqlException exc)
            {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For an more advanced example visit the given link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very informative. I will go through all the information and see if I can get it to work. Fingers crossed.